# Pycharm erroe on run causes the gui script to disappear

Tags: pycharm

When I run a script from within Pycharm and when an error is encountered, the error is correctly reported in the console but the script exits after a few seconds. Is it possible to make it not come out until I stop it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the debugger? You can use it to stop your program anywhere you want and see the value of all variables at the point. It's super valuable.

Comment: The debugger is my main tool, but sometimes it happens that a patch creates a problem elsewhere and when you run the project it crashes and the GUI disappears after a few seconds. At that point I use the debugger again but it's annoying that the GUI disappears. IMHO of course

Comment: Got it. It sounds like a problem for Jetbrains tech support.